# Passing Func<bool> argument in constructor causing issue with Ninject

Tags: ninject

I am creating a factory using interface as

```
public interface ICommandFactory
{
  ICommand CreateCommand(Action executeMethod);
  ICommand CreateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod);
}

public class DelegateCommand : DelegateCommand<object>
{
    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod)
        : base(o => executeMethod())
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
        : base(o => executeMethod(), o => canExecuteMethod())
    {
    }
}

public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod)
        : this(executeMethod, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {

    }
}
```

My Ninject binding is done using

```
_kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("xyz*")
                        .SelectAllClasses()                                
                        .BindAllInterfaces());

_kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("xyz*")
                        .SelectAllInterfaces()
                        .EndingWith("Factory")
                        .BindToFactory()
                        .Configure(c => c.InSingletonScope()));
```

When I call in my view model it is causing activation exception although I tried with Named binding.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public ICommand SaveCommand {get; private set;}

  public MyViewModel(ICommandFactory commandFactory)
  {
    SaveCommand = commandFactory.CreateCommand(Save, () => SelectedTask != null);
  }
}
```

The exception is caused in DelegateCommand's constructor on 'o => canExecuteMethod()' line. Also, I cannot use constructor param passing in Ninject as my logic for canExecute is in my ViewModel. Any solution or fix is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by Ninject.Extensions.Factory creating a binding for `Func<>`'s.

When you are using said extension, ninject is configured so that you can inject a `Func<>` as a factory. `Func<bool>` is basically bound like

```
kernel.Bind<Func<bool>>().ToMethod(() => 
{
    return (Func<bool>) = () => kernel.Get<bool>();
}
```

Now this is paired with the fact, that ninject will use the public constructor with the most parameters it can resolve. That means, even if you use `CreateCommand(Action executeMethod);`, ninject will use the `public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)` constructor and inject a "bool factory" as the `Func<bool>` parameter.

### Workarounds

**Wrapping the Func in an interface**

There's many ways to do this, let me show you one:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Wrapped { get; set; }
}
```

and adapt the factory to:

```
public interface ICommandFactory
{
  ICommand CreateCommand(Action executeMethod, Wrapper<Func<bool>> canExecuteMethod);
}
```

and the delegate command constructor:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Wrapper<Func<bool>> canExecuteMethod)
    {
    }
}
```

**Removing the factory extensions Func bindings**

See [Stop Ninject from binding Func<T, T, bool> automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862138/stop-ninject-from-binding-funct-t-bool-automatically/24863850#24863850)